# Timeout while launching EC2 instances from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have been trying to launch a new EC2 instance as well as add a piece of string data to my SQS through lambda in response to an object upload event in my s3 bucket.

I have been able to successfully to update my SQS but has been unable to initialise the new EC2 instance. Despite setting the time allocation to the lambda function to the maximum time of 5mins and increasing memory allocation, an operation timeout error continuously surface.

My code is as below. Can anyone point out what are the potential causes for such an error? While I have stuck my whole piece of code here for reference, the area concerning the launch is towards the end of the code.

Thank you so much!

```
console.log('Loading function');

var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
var sqs = new aws.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
var ecs = new aws.ECS({apiVersion: '2014-11-13'});
var ec2 = new aws.EC2({apiVersion: '2015-10-01'});

// Check if the given key suffix matches a suffix in the whitelist. Return true if it matches, false otherwise.
exports.checkS3SuffixWhitelist = function(key, whitelist) {
    if(!whitelist){ return true; }
    if(typeof whitelist == 'string'){ return key.match(whitelist + '$') }
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(whitelist) === '[object Array]') {
        for(var i = 0; i < whitelist.length; i++) {
            if(key.match(whitelist[i] + '$')) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
    console.log(
        'Unsupported whitelist type (' + Object.prototype.toString.call(whitelist) +
        ') for: ' + JSON.stringify(whitelist)
    );
    return false;
};


exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log('Received event:');

    //Read in the configuration file
    var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf8'));
    if(!config.hasOwnProperty('s3_key_suffix_whitelist')) {
        config.s3_key_suffix_whitelist = false;
    }
    console.log('Config: ' + JSON.stringify(config));

    var name = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    if(!exports.checkS3SuffixWhitelist(name, config.s3_key_suffix_whitelist)) {
        context.fail('Suffix for key: ' + name + ' is not in the whitelist')
    }


    // Get the object from the event and show its key
    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key
    };
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            var message = "Error getting object " + key + " from bucket " + bucket +
                ". Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.";
            console.log(message);
            context.fail(message);
        } else {
            console.log('CONTENT TYPE:', key);
            context.succeed(key);
        }
    });


    //Sending the image key as a message to SQS and starting a new instance on EC2
    async.waterfall([
        function(next){
            var params = {
                MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
                QueueUrl: config.queue
            };
            console.log("IN QUEUE FUNCTION");
            sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) { console.warn('Error while sending message: ' + err); }
                    else { console.info('Message sent, ID: ' + data.MessageId); }
                    next(err);
            });
        }, 
        function (next) {

            console.log("INITIALIZING ECS");
            var params = {
                ImageId: 'ami-e559b485',
                MinCount: 1,
                MaxCount: 1,
                DryRun: true,
                InstanceType: 't2.micro',
                KeyName: 'malpem2102',
                SubnetId: 'subnet-e8607e8d'

            }

            ec2.runInstances(params, function(err,data){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    context.fail('Error', "Error getting file: " + err);
                    return;
                } else{
                    var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
                    console.log("Created instance ", instanceId);
                    context.suceed("Created instance");
                }
            });
        }
    ], function(err){
        if (err) {
                context.fail('An error has occurred: ' + err);
            }
            else {
                context.succeed('Successfully processed Amazon S3 URL.');
            }
        }
    );

};
```